# How to detect the circles in the image using opencv 3 in c++

Tags: c++, windows, opencv

How Can I detect the circles and count the number in this image. I'm new to open cv and c++.Can any one help with this issue. I tried with hough circle . But didn't work .

The skeletonized binary image is as follows.

[image: input image]

Comment: I think your question is too broad.

Comment: **Find contours** -> **fit ellipse**

Comment: Hough circle won't work duh.... there is no circle in the first place. Your only bet is approximation, using ellipses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from this image (I removed the border):

[image]

You can follow this approach:

1) Use `findContour` to get the contours.

2) Keep only internal contours. You can do that checking the sign of the area returned by `contourArea(..., true)`. You'll get the 2 internal contours:

[image]

3) Now that you have the two contours, you can find a circle with `minEnclosingCircle` (in blue), or fit an ellipse with `fitEllipse` (in red):

[image]

Here the full code for reference:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() 
{
    Mat1b img = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    // Get contours
    vector<vector<Point>> contours;
    findContours(img, contours, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    // Create output image
    Mat3b out;
    cvtColor(img, out, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

    Mat3b outContours = out.clone();

    // Get internal contours
    vector<vector<Point>> internalContours;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i) {
        // Find orientation: CW or CCW
        double area = contourArea(contours[i], true);
        if (area >= 0) {
            // Internal contour
            internalContours.push_back(contours[i]);

            // Draw with different color
            drawContours(outContours, contours, i, Scalar(rand() & 255, rand() & 255, rand() & 255));
        }
    }

    // Get circles 
    for (const auto& cnt : internalContours) {
        Point2f center;
        float radius;
        minEnclosingCircle(cnt, center, radius);

        // Draw circle in blue
        circle(out, center, radius, Scalar(255, 0, 0));
    }

    // Get ellipses
    for (const auto& cnt : internalContours) {
        RotatedRect rect = fitEllipse(cnt);

        // Draw ellipse in red
        ellipse(out, rect, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
    }

    imshow("Out", out);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind consideration. I tried with your code. However I get this. I was unable to find the error. :(  "Unhandled exception at 0x000007FDA3294388 (ucrtbase.dll) in ConsoleApplication1.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal."  This problem occurs at the line findContours(img, contours, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

Comment: make sure that you're loading correctly the input image (the one in my answer, not the one in your question!)... Otherwise I don't know... this works perfectly on my pc

Comment: Yep, "right click" and "save image as". Try from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qN0z.png)

Comment: Yes (3.2, vc14 x86), opencv code is correct. You probably have linking issue or something else...

Comment: Could I please know the libraries and links you are using in your application. Do you use c++ API ?

Comment: @ Miki Your code nicely work in open cv 2.4 version. I don't know why it's not working in my one. :(

Comment: @ Miki  Finally it worked. I have had a linking problem. Thank you for your help. Appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all you have to find all contours at your image (see function cv::findContours).
2. You have to analyse these contours (check it for accordance to your requirements).

P.S. The figure at the picture is definitely not circle. So I can't say exactly how do you have to check received contours.